# Difference between DATE & TIME values in seconds (Excel)

Tags: excel, date, datetime, time

In my Excel sheet I have a column with dates and times which looks like this: 27.09.2016  14:02:03

I would like to get the difference between each pair of date in seconds.

For Example: 10.10.2016 13:00:10 - 10.10.2016 13:00:00 = 10s

If I do

```
= A 1- A2
```

I get 0,000115741

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value is in days (24 hours)  not in seconds.  10 seconds are (almost) exactly that fraction of 24 hours that you get as the answer.  Multiply it with 60x60x24  and  you get your 10 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

Alex. S response is good enough, you can also multiply what you are getting by 86400 (which is the result of 60*60*24, you just save some operations) There are other alternatives you can explore. You can take a look to this link:https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/06/24/calculate-time-excel/